# $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ (,)=(−,) .

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

find $f\circ f$ for the function $f\colon \mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ (,)=(−,)
I know that if (,)=(−,), then () is its inverse reflected about the -axis. If this is the case then $f\circ f$ = f^-1(−f^-1(−)). I also know that it may equal (−,−) but I have no idea how (−,)=(−,-). I also know that its got something to do with vectors or scalars but I'm still stuck. I need someone to explain it in detail for me.

I am not sure on how to do this question. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You have already posted this same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3636124/446262).

Comment: Why do you keep on posting the same question ?

Comment: Because i need a proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your question right, you just want to know what $f \circ f$ is for your function.
Observe that $(f \circ f)(x,y) = f(f(x,y)) = f(-y, x) = (-x, -y)$.

Comment: yes thank you but how does (−,)=(−,−) , that's the part that I don't understand so could you please explain.

Comment: Since $f(x,y) = (-y,x)$, for example inserting the point $(1,3)$ yields $f(1,3) = (-3,1)$. But now you insert $(-y, x)$. So the first input just gets transferred to the second and the second input gets transferred to the first and additionally its sign is changed. Hence $f(-y, x) = (-x,-y)$

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused because you have $x$ and $y$ in the definition of $f$ and the argument of $f \circ f$, so it might help to replace it somewhere.

So $f$ is a function that maps $(x, y)$ to $(-y,x)$. To get $f \circ f$, we need to apply $f$ again. Now let $u=-y$ and $v=x$. From the definition, we have that
$$f(u,v)=(-v,u)=(-x,-y)$$
So
$$(f \circ f)(x,y)=(-x,-y)$$